# Indenting description lists

Tags: lists, indentation, description

Is there a way to change how description lists are indented?

I have something like:

```
Normal text

List item
List Item
```

I would like something like:

```
Normal text

    List item
    List Item
```

Comment: If you have access to Lamport's book, the many settings affecting description lists (and other lists) are described there in great detail.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I recommend to use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package which offers a lot of features for customizing lists - both fine tuning and also consistent list adjustment. For example, just by `\setlist[description]{leftmargin=1cm,labelindent=1cm}` you could indent the description list by 1 cm. Raise `leftmargin` or use any value you like for the arguments. More can be found in the package documentation.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=\parindent,labelindent=\parindent}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
left aligned text
\begin{description}
 \item[One] first item
 \item[Two] second item
 \item[Three] third item
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `enumitem`, you could even specify it locally, case-by-case, using optional arguments:

```
\begin{description}[labelindent=1cm]
...
```

Comment: Note: `\parindent` doesn't work if you have another description within a description item. `cm` seems to be ok.

Comment: Multi-line description items might look better if they're indented with hanging indent: `\setlist[description]{leftmargin=1cm,labelindent=0cm}`. Cheers!

Comment: A quick note: `enumitem` is in [conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer) with beamer.

Comment: `\parindent` also won't work as expected if it is in fact set to zero, e.g. by using the `parskip` package. I find that using `labelindent=\leftmargin` (which defaults to `25pt` BTW) works well. Modifying `leftmargin` itself isn't necessary.

Answer (score 13):

I like Stefan's answer a lot, but if you'd prefer not to install a new package and are okay with a hacky solution, you could just enclose the description in a `quote` or `quotation` environment.

Comment: What would this hacky solution be in this case? I am new to LaTeX and do not know how I would implement this.

Answer (score 8):

redefine the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewenvironment{description}[1][0pt]
  {\list{}{\labelwidth=0pt \leftmargin=#1
   \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
  {\endlist}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

default text
\begin{description}
 \item[foo] bar
 \item[foobar] bar
 \item[foo] bar
\end{description}

\begin{description}[1cm]
 \item[foo] bar
 \item[foobar] bar
 \item[foo] bar
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that the only way? Is there no way to achieve that in case-by-case scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you don't want to install another package, you can do what I've done below, since embedded lists are indented. You'll have to hit  for each time you do this when you compile, though.

```
\begin{description}

\begin{description}

 \item[One]first item

 \item[Two]second item

 \item[Three]third item

\end{description}

\end{description}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it works?

Comment: It works, but throws an error for a missing `\item`. Like [Punya](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9769/45342) answered, using `quote` instead of `description` is then cleaner.

Comment: If it throws an error, then by definition it doesn't work. It's *Very Poor Practice Indeed* (VPPI) to ignore (La)TeX's error messages because the final output looks OK.