# Trouble combining enumitem and beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, incompatibility, overlays, enumitem

I have trouble combining two things for a set of slides:

1. Adjust item separation globally
2. Use default overlays of lists locally (parameter `[<+->]`)

I use `enumitem` for 1. but it seems to disturb `beamer` quite a bit. To begin with, I had to employ [some trickery](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/does-enumitem-conflict-with-beamer-for-lists/24491#24491) to not have `enumtitle` overwrite the selected slide style.

With the linked solution in effect, adding `[<+->]` to an `itemize` does not have any effect at all. I would expect it to overwrite the global setting, but evidently it does not.

How can I achieve 1. and 2. simultaneously?

*Minimal failing example:*

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{itemsep=1.5em,%
  label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}%
        \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item On slide 1
    \item On slide 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you already mentioned, [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) "disturbs" [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). This is because the document class (`beamer` in this case) defines (or redefines) all the necessary commands/macros and environments to it's liking. Then, each loaded package does the same sequentially. As such, since `enumitem` *follows* the document class, it redefines the `itemize` (and other) environments, thereby removing `beamer`'s modified overlay specification.

It is possible to tap into the main level list environment parameters by patching the command `\@listI`. The following shows the definition of the three levels contained in [`beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty):

```
%
% List stuff
%

\setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii  {2em}
\setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
\setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
\addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}

\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \topsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2.5\p@
            \parsep 0\p@
            \itemsep3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus3\p@}
\let\@listI\@listi
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \topsep    2\p@ \@plus1\p@ \@minus2\p@
              \parsep    0\p@   \@plus\p@
              \itemsep   \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \topsep    2\p@ \@plus1\p@ \@minus2\p@
              \parsep    0\p@   \@plus\p@
              \itemsep   \parsep}
```

A patch using `\patchcmd`, as provided by [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), that changes `\itemsep3\p@` to `\itemsep2em` (say) modifies the command globally from `3pt` to `2em`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@listI}{\itemsep3\p@}{\itemsep2em}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The use of the `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` pair is required, since the macro definition of `\@listI` contains `@`. Note that this patch does not modify the shrink (`3pt`) or stretch (`2pt`) of `\itemsep`.

Comment: Looks clean and works well, thanks! Of course, `enumitem` offers the useful possibility to change `itemsep` locally, too, but I guess you can't have everything.

Comment: Patching `\@listii` in the same way does not seem to have any effect. Is there something special to consider?

Comment: I just patched `\patchcmd{\@listii}{\itemsep\parsep}{\itemsep3\p@}{}{}` to have slightly sparser spacing of sub-lists, and that command worked for me. How did you try to patch listii?

Comment: This answer did not work for me. However [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225737/73149) did.

Answer (score 16):

Adding `\tracingall` shows that TeX is spinning around a cyclic definition of `\\description` which is an internal saved version of the description environment.
It's quite easy for this to happen if two packages are saving the"original" version of something.

```
\\description [#1]->\beamer@origdescription 
#1<-

\beamer@origdescription ->\@protected@testopt \description \\description {}

\@protected@testopt #1->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \expandafter \@testopt 
\else \@x@protect #1\fi 

\@testopt #1#2->\kernel@ifnextchar [{#1}{#1[{#2}]}
#1<-\\description 
#2<-

\kernel@ifnextchar #1#2#3->\let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reser


\@ifnch ->\ifx \@let@token \@sptoken \let \reserved@c \@xifnch \else \ifx \@let

\reserved@c ->\\description [{}]

\\description [#1]->\beamer@origdescription 
#1<-
```

While it's easy to see why TeX hangs, fixing it depends what you want to do.
You could re-assert the beamer or enumitem version. But if you want an environment with the features of both that may take a bit more coordination and knowledge of both packages neither of which I have this morning:-)

for example this keeps beamers defininition and stops the looping.

```
\let\olddescription\description
\let\oldenddescription\enddescription
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\description\olddescription
\let\enddescription\oldenddescription
```

Answer (score 15):

You can redefine the `\itemize` command as defined in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`; in the following example I defined a global `itemsep` length of `2em` (the line signaled with `%NEW`) for this command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\setlength\itemsep{2em}% NEW
        \def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's a portion of the resulting third slide:

[image]