# Increase the gap before and after the dots in inline list

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

How to increase the gap before and after the dot?

[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize*}
  \item[] First point
  \item Second point
  \item Third point
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See documentation: `itemjoin` and `afterlabel`

Comment: `\begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\hspace{1em}}]`

Comment: I added the answer...

Comment: Please don't edit answers into questions. Either the question is a dupe, in which case the linked question covers it, or it's not, in which case this question should be edited to show why that is.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The linked question does not deal with space. I have asked similar question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149101/inline-arrangement-using-enumitem/149288?noredirect=1#149288