# Problem with tabto package

Tags: tabto

I'm having a problem with the otherwise excellent "tabto" package: the baseline of large text positioned after the first tab stop isn't calculated correctly, leading to ugly overlaps with the previous line.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

Here is a list of some items:

\NumTabs{3}
\noindent
(a) An item.\tab
(b) Another item. \tab
(c) Again, an item. \tab
(d) {\huge A rather large item.} \tab
(e) The final item.

\vspace{12pt}

Here is a list of some items:

\NumTabs{2}
\noindent
(a) An item.\tab
(b) Another item. \tab
(c) Again, an item. \tab
(d) {\huge A rather large item.} \tab
(e) The final item.

\end{document}
```

The first set of tabbed items looks great. In the second "A rather large item" overlaps the text on the line above.

If anyone has a suggestion for a workaround, either in my document or as a patch to the package, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can use the environment `enumerate` with is more suitable at this place.

Comment: I didn't see an obvious way to use `enumerate` (I assume `paralist` style) with a fixed number of tab-stops (which is the requirement in this case).

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51086/add-second-enumeration-item-on-the-same-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the tabular environment, which was a much better approach than what I'd been trying. The other answers were fine, but none worked given the constraints I had. Anyway, here's what I used in case it's useful (or could be improved).

```
\int_new:N \l__tabs_columns
\dim_new:N \l__tabs_space

\newcounter{tabstop}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \thetabstop{} {\itemstyle{\alph{tabstop}}}

\cs_new:Nn \l__tabs_item: {
  \int_compare:nT
    { \value{tabstop} != 0 }
    {
      \int_compare:nTF
      { \int_mod:nn{ \value{tabstop} }{ \l__tabs_columns }  == 0 }
      { \\ }
      { & }
    }
  \refstepcounter{tabstop}
  \thetabstop {~}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {tabs}{m} {
  \setlength {\tabcolsep} {0pt}
  \setcounter {tabstop} {0}
  \int_set:Nn \l__tabs_columns {#1}
  \dim_set:Nn \l__tabs_space { \textwidth / \l__tabs_columns }
  \cs_set_eq:NN \item \l__tabs_item:
  \par \addvspace{0.10\onelineskip} \noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{*{\l__tabs_columns}{p{\l__tabs_space}}}
}{
  \end{tabular}
  \par \addvspace{0.20\onelineskip} \noindent \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

I use it like so:

```
Give the domain of definition of each function $f$ defined below, and describe
or sketch its graph:
\begin{tabs}{3}
  \item\label{first} $f(x) = 1/(1 + x^2)$
  \item\label{second} $f(x,y) = 4 - x^2 - y^2$
  \item $f(x) = x/(x - 1)$
  \item $f(x,y) = 1/(x^2 - y^2)$
  \item $f(x,y) = \tfrac{1}{2}(1/x + 1/y)$
  \item $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
  \item $f(x,y) = x^y$.
\end{tabs}
```

Seems to work without any issues for me.

Answer (score 5):

Now this is an answer of the type: there is a package for that. `:)` It's called: ta-dah! - [multienum](http://ctan.org/pkg/multenum)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multienum}

\begin{document}

Here is a list of some items:

\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxx{An item.}{Another item.}{Again, an item.}
\mitemxox{\huge A rather large item.}{The final item.}
\end{multienumerate}

\vspace{12pt}

\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxo{An item.}{Another item.}
\mitemxxo{Again, an item.}{\huge A rather large item.}
\mitemx{The final item.}{}
\end{multienumerate}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unrelated to `tabto` you should never use a size changing command without including the end of paragraph within the scope otherwise the baseline spacing will be wrong.

Not sure either is that lovely but you can go

```
(d) \huge A rather large item. \tab\normalsize
```

which makes

[image]

Or you can go

```
(d) {\huge A rather large item.\par} \tab
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My apologies -- my example was a simplified version of my actual case. The problem appears to exist any time a tabbed item is larger than previous items, for whatever reason.