# Horizontal distance between items and subitems

Tags: itemize

I am making a beamer presentation and I found that the horizontal distance between items and subitems is bigger than I expected. I tried to change it by using `\addtolength`, but the lines of the subitem are misaligned. How can I change it?

Comment: A MWE would help. I was going to recommend using the `enumitem` package, but [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer) says that `beamer` and `enumitem` do not play well together. On the other hand, this same post gives you a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the value of `\leftmarginii`, the 2nd level indent.  Here, after showing the `beamer` default, I made it half the value of `\leftmargini`, the 1st level indent.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
text
\begin{itemize}
\item item
\begin{itemize}
\item subitem
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\leftmarginii=.5\leftmargini\relax
text
\begin{itemize}
\item item
\begin{itemize}
\item subitem
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]