# Names of items aligning out of frame in Beamer

Tags: beamer, align, itemize

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{meh...}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[Hello] World
    \item[Hey! Hello?] D'oh!
  \end{itemize}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The names of the items ("Hey!" in this example) get out of the frame and are not visible.

I would prefer to keep as much of the current template intact if possible.

I tried with a description environment at first, but I don't understand the alignment it does.

Comment: Not really a beamer issue; if you did the same thing in the article class the second item label sticks out into the left margin.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang As I note in my answer, `beamer` and `enumitem` don't play well together: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `description` environment the alignment is equal to length the text into the `[]` brackets after `\begin{description}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{meh...}
  \begin{description}[Hey! Hello?]
    \item[Hello] World
    \item[Hey! Hello?] D'oh!
  \end{description}

  \begin{description}[Hello]
    \item[Hello] World
    \item[Hey! Hello?] D'oh!
  \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Put the longest label into brackets and you should be fine.

Comment: I wish LaTeX was a bit more clever, but this seems to be the best possible solution. I guess LuaTeX and similar environments would have no trouble in counting the number of characters, but I prefer to stick to the standard pdflatex for a while. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package with the `align=left` option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{align=left}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{meh...}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[Hello] World World World World World World World World World World World World
    \item[Hey! Hello?] D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh! D'oh!
  \end{itemize}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Answer (score 1):

This uses no additional packages, but resets the value of `\itemindent` length inside the list.

In addition to the fact that an alternative `enumitem` solution removes the color of the label, it is said that `enumitem` and `beamer` do not play well together: [Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{meh...}
  \begin{itemize}
    \itemindent=1in
    \item[Hello] World
    \item[Hey! Hello?] D'oh!
  \end{itemize}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]