# LaTeX Beamer: Define \itemsep globally

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize, templates

In LaTeX Beamer, I'm trying to set `\itemsep` globally.

I've already tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\setlength{\itemsep}{5ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
%       \setlength{\itemsep}{5ex}  % this would work locally..
        \item Test1
        \item Test2
        \item Test3
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I would prefer a solution that allows to define different spacing for body, subbody, subsubbody, etc., if possible.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yout code won't work because the `itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin` template is used *before* the `\list` internally used by `itemize`.

You can patch `\itemize` (original definition in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`):

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\setlength{\itemsep}{5ex}\def\makelabel}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Test1
        \item Test2
        \item Test3
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `\itemize` as defined by `beamer` has an optional argument,  using `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` might produce undesired results. The `\xpatchcmd` from the `xpatch` package was designed to deal with these cases.

### Update

In comments, it has been requested to be able to independently control the separation for the three allowed nesting levels; this can also be easily done using a conditional on `\@itemdepth`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
     \setlength\itemsep{3ex}% separation for first level
   \else
     \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
       \setlength\itemsep{2ex}% separation for second level
     \else
       \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
         \setlength\itemsep{0.5ex}% separation for third level
   \fi\fi\fi\def\makelabel
  }
 {}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First subitem.
  \item Second subitem.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First subsubitem.
    \item Second subsubitem.
    \item Third subsubitem.
    \end{itemize}
  \item Third subitem.
  \end{itemize}
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your one appeared while I was trying mine. Care to tell why `\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\setlength\itemsep{2.0em}}` does not work?

Comment: @Masroor Your try with `\AtBeginEnvironment` (from `etoolbox`) executes the code immediately before `\itemize` so it won't have effect.

Comment: So, `etoolbox` can *not* be used in this case?

Comment: @Masroor since `\itemize` is defined in `beamer` with an optional argument, using `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` might produce undesired results. `\xpatchcmd` was written to deal with those cases correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Was curious. I seem to have got my answer. Already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but it looks a little bit like a "hack" to me. If it would be possible to make `\setbeamertemplate` work, one could use different spacing for body, subbody, subsubbody, etc. which would be a great advantage.

Comment: @Mario That can be easily done also. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Is there a way to use this with elastic spaces rather than fixed heights? I tried using `stretch(factor)` but no spacing appeared in the output.

Comment: Could you please also give an example to set spacing for enumerate within beamer as well? Thank you!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for this. Do you also know how I can change the separation between "First Item" and "First Subitem"? This patch doesn't seem to control it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The answer likely will involve the `topsep` setting.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I would like to reproduce this for enumerate environments, can you help ?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina @BambOo The trivial idea to replace `\itemize` in the `xpatch`command with `\enumerate` didn't work for me. How to do this for enumerate?

Comment: @GertVdE, still no idea how to do that

Comment: @BambOo for `enumerate` you have to patch `\beamer@enum@`, see my answer...

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225737/38080), I use this:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@beamer@setsep}{%
\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
     \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepi}% separation for first level
   \else
     \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
       \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepii}% separation for second level
     \else
       \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
         \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepiii}% separation for third level
   \fi\fi\fi}
\newlength{\my@beamer@itemsepi}\setlength{\my@beamer@itemsepi}{3ex}
\newlength{\my@beamer@itemsepii}\setlength{\my@beamer@itemsepii}{1.5ex}
\newlength{\my@beamer@itemsepiii}\setlength{\my@beamer@itemsepiii}{1.5ex}
\newcommand\setlistsep[3]{%
    \setlength{\my@beamer@itemsepi}{#1}%
    \setlength{\my@beamer@itemsepii}{#2}%
    \setlength{\my@beamer@itemsepiii}{#3}%
}
\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\my@beamer@setsep\def\makelabel}
 {}
 {}

\xpatchcmd{\beamer@enum@}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\my@beamer@setsep\def\makelabel}
 {}
 {}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth, T]
        \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
            % First column
            \begin{itemize}
                \item First item.
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item First subitem.
                        \item Second subitem.
                            \begin{itemize}
                                \item First subsubitem.
                                \item Second subsubitem.
                                \item Third subsubitem.
                            \end{itemize}
                        \item Third subitem.
                    \end{itemize}
                \item Second item.
                \item Third item.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}%
        \hfill%
        \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
            % second column
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item First item.
                    \begin{enumerate}
                        \item First subitem.
                        \item Second subitem.
                            \begin{enumerate}
                                \item First subsubitem.
                                \item Second subsubitem.
                                \item Third subsubitem.
                            \end{enumerate}
                        \item Third subitem.
                    \end{enumerate}
                \item Second item.
                \item Third item.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

so that I can then do `\setlistsep{2ex}{1ex}{1ex}` in the slide where I need to change the values.

[image]

If you want also to add to the separation of the first item in a sublist, you can change the `\my@beamer@setsep` to:

```latex
\newcommand{\my@beamer@setsep}{%
\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
     \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepi}% separation for first level
   \else
     \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
       \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepii}% separation for second level
       \setlength\topsep{\my@beamer@itemsepii}% separation for second level
     \else
       \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
         \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepiii}% separation for third level
         \setlength\topsep{\my@beamer@itemsepiii}% separation for second level
   \fi\fi\fi}
```

to obtain

[image]

...or maybe it's better to use the *previous* `itemsep`  as `topsep`:

```
\newcommand{\my@beamer@setsep}{%
\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
     \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepi}% separation for first level
   \else
     \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
       \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepii}% separation for second level
       \setlength\topsep{\my@beamer@itemsepi}% separation for second level
     \else
       \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
         \setlength\itemsep{\my@beamer@itemsepiii}% separation for third level
         \setlength\topsep{\my@beamer@itemsepii}% separation for second level
   \fi\fi\fi}
```

[image]

(just a matter of taste)

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks !