# How do I make a really long bullet point next not dissappear off the left of the page?

Tags: itemize

I'm trying to put text as my "bullet point" but it's far too long as extends beyond the left of the page. What can I do to stop it doing this?

```
\begin{itemize}

  \item[\textsc{Contact Information}] 

   Address: Address \\

   Telephone: Telephone \\

   E-mail: Email

  \item[\textsc{Education}] 

   Etc

\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `description` or `labeling`(KOMA-script)? It isn't recommended at all to use long texts there. You could even be on the search for `paragraph` or `minisec` (KOMA-script). Can you show us a compilable real world example?

Comment: I'm trying to do a CV, where the "bullet points" are fields such as Contact Information or Education.

Comment: Would this help? [Make the lines of a description item line up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155432)

Comment: Also don't leave a blank line after `\\ ` (Latex will be complaining about underfull hbox of badness 10000 (which is infinitely bad)

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from the page of Gonzalo at [LaTeX Beamer: Define \itemsep globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225736/latex-beamer-define-itemsep-globally/225737#225737), one can redefine indentation parameters like `\leftmargin` and `\itemindent` by patching the definition of `\itemize`.

EDIT: I also show another way with stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch,lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\def\defaultitemindent{0pt}
\def\defaultleftmargin{\the\leftmargin}
\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\setlength{\itemindent}{\defaultitemindent}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\defaultleftmargin}%
   \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\def\makelabel}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
\parindent 0pt
DEFAULT:
\begin{itemize}
\item[Really Long Text] \lipsum[4] 
\item[Short] text
\end{itemize}

STACK:
\begin{itemize}
\item[\smash{\Longunderstack[l]{Really\\ Long\\ Text}}] \lipsum[4] 
\item[Short] text
\end{itemize}

CHANGE ITEMINDENT
\def\defaultitemindent{15ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item[Really Long Text] \lipsum[4] 
\item[Short] text
\end{itemize}

CHANGE LEFTMARGIN
\def\defaultleftmargin{20ex}
\def\defaultitemindent{0ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item[Really Long Text] \lipsum[4] 
\item[Short] text
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `align=left` option with [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem), or the`description` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[Really Long Label] Text 
\end{itemize}

\medskip
\begin{itemize}[align=left]
    \item[Really Long Label] Using \verb|align=left| option 
\end{itemize}

\medskip
\begin{description}
    \item[Really Long Label] Using \verb|description| 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But how can I align multiple fields (see original post)?

Comment: @RyanNg: It is not clear from your updated post how you want things aligned. Can you also post an image of the desired output. Also, perhaps you should consider using `tabular`.