# Why does itemsep not work in setbeamertemplate?

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize

I'm trying to change the spacing between `itemize` items in a beamer frame.

I've read that you should adjust beamer settings using the `setbeamertemplate` command so I'd like to follow that advice.

I can make *some* changes, like making the font `\small` and adjusting the vertical spacing before the itemize.

But wherever I try and put `vspace` or `itemsep` it seems to make no difference to the spacing between items.

Why is this, and how can I achieve, say, 5cm spacing between items using `setbeamertemplate`?

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% itemsep does nothing here:
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\vspace{1cm}\tiny\itemsep5cm}
% vspace and itemsep do nothing here:
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\vspace{5cm}\itemsep5cm---}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}{subtitle}
Foo
\begin{itemize}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: Item separation doesn't work]

Comment: I've just found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225736/31839) which looks like it might be a duplicate. Although the answer doesn't use `setbeamertemplate`. Hmm....

Comment: To change the font size better use `\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\tiny}`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412275/36296 for an example how to change the spacing using beamer templates.