# Improving Arguelles, a beamer theme, removing enumitem

Tags: beamer, enumerate, enumitem, themes

I found a very neat `beamer` theme (`Arguelles`, https://github.com/piazzai/arguelles) however there are three things that I believe are troublesome with the theme. I am trying to improve them but I am finding myself short of the required knowledge in the `beamer` class and `LaTeX` in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question concerns the use of the `enumitem` package. The theme loads `enumitem`, which is a great package, I use it for articles, but is not recommended with `beamer` ([Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer)). I find that I can circumvent this by commenting line 49 of `beamerthemeArguelles.sty` to not load `enumitem`, and comment lines 46-55 of `beamerinnerthemeArguelles.sty`. However, this loses the list and description style of the theme. Any idea how to rewrite the lines 46-55 into something `beamer` can use?

Comment: Can you please only ask one question per post?

Comment: Right, I'll split it into three questions then.

Comment: @ Cryme Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `itemize (sub(sub))item` templates like this to use the same symbols as Arguelles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Arguelles}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\circ$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{$\cdot$}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{
  \setlength{\leftmargini}{0.4cm}
  \setlength{\leftmarginii}{0.4cm}
  \setlength{\leftmarginiii}{0.4cm}
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{
  \setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5cm}
  \setlength{\leftmarginii}{0.6cm}
  \setlength{\leftmarginiii}{0.8cm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
why does this theme colour the first frame even if there is no title page?
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
      \frametitle{A frame with title and subtitle}
      \framesubtitle{Subtitle here}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \par
      Itemized list:
      \begin{itemize}
            \item Lorem ipsum
            \item Dolor sit amet
                  \begin{itemize}
                        \item Consectetur
                        \item Adipiscing elit
                  \end{itemize}
            \item Sed do eiusmod
                  \begin{itemize}
                        \item Tempor incididunt
                              \begin{itemize}
                                    \item Ut labore et dolore
                                    \item Magna aliqua
                              \end{itemize}
                  \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
      \frametitle{A frame with title and subtitle}
      \framesubtitle{Subtitle here}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \par
      Itemized list:
      \begin{enumerate}
            \item Lorem ipsum
            \item Dolor sit amet
                  \begin{enumerate}
                        \item Consectetur
                        \item Adipiscing elit
                  \end{enumerate}
            \item Sed do eiusmod
                  \begin{enumerate}
                        \item Tempor incididunt
                              \begin{enumerate}
                                    \item Ut labore et dolore
                                    \item Magna aliqua
                              \end{enumerate}
                  \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's true but what about removing the margins on the left and having the right height separations between items?

Comment: @Cryme See my updated answer, now with adjusted leftmargini (fine tune the value as you like)

Comment: Great, I have made it work for the left margin. Any idea about the height separations? I was reading answers from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225736/latex-beamer-define-itemsep-globally but fiddling with the different heights does not get the ```enumitem``` result (I would like the nested lists not only to be tighter in height, but also vertically closer to their parent item).

Comment: Actually ```\vspace``` can do the job alright, let me post an answer with the entire code in case anyone is interested. The only difference now it seems is with the handling of descriptions.

Comment: You can adjust `\itemsep` at the start of the list

Comment: That's true, you can do that for each list individually, but you can also have the specification in the inner theme. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is the code (replacing lines 46-55 of `beamerinnerthemeArguelles.sty`)that best replicated the results using the `enumitem` package. It requires the package `xpatch`. There is still some difference with the handling of `description` environments, but hopefully `itemize` and `enumerate` environments look faithful to the original theme.

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\circ$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{$\cdot$}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\theenumi.\theenumii.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii.}

\setbeamertemplate{description item}{\normalfont\itshape\insertdescriptionitem}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}
\settowidth{\leftmarginii}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize subitem}}
\addtolength{\leftmarginii}{\labelsep}
\settowidth{\leftmarginiii}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}}
\addtolength{\leftmarginiii}{\labelsep}
}

\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
     \setlength\itemsep{0em}% separation for first level
   \else
     \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
        \vspace{-0.5em}
       \setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}% separation for second level
     \else
        \vspace{-0.5em}
       \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
         \setlength\itemsep{-.5em}% separation for third level
   \fi\fi\fi\def\makelabel
  }
 {}
 {}

\xpatchcmd{\beamer@enum@}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
     \setlength\itemsep{0em}% separation for first level
   \else
     \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
        \vspace{-0.5em}
       \setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}% separation for second level
     \else
        \vspace{-0.5em}
       \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
         \setlength\itemsep{-.5em}% separation for third level
   \fi\fi\fi\def\makelabel
  }
 {}
 {}
```