# Redefining the item label in beamerarticle

Tags: enumitem, description, beamerarticle

I want to use `$\bullet$` for the item label. In most LaTeX classes I would use

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=$\bullet$}
```

However this won't work in `beamerarticle` since `enumitem` doesn't play nice with everything `beamer`-related (see for instance [Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer))

Here is an example that pdflatex will fail to compile (in TeXLive 2014).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setitemize{label=$\bullet$}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[first item] blabla
\item[second item] blabla
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Note that I don't want to redefine the default description environment in article, only replace the "-" label used in the itemize environment with a $\bullet$.

I also tried

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
```

but it needs to be put it in every document. There is a conflict with the french option of babel. See for instance:

with test.cls containing

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\endinput
```

the following uses the regular "-" for item labels whereas it uses bullets if babel is not loaded with the french option.

```
\documentclass{test}
\title{Essai}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item blabla
\item blabla
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is `\labelitemi` and not `\labelitem`... and why do you say that it doesn't work if placed in a `.cls` file?

Comment: I investigated further and noticed that the problem arises from a conflict with \RequirePackage[french]{babel}

Comment: @wilk You're right and an answer has been provided below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `french` module for `babel`, you need to do the change `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Essai}

\RequirePackage[french]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item blabla
\item blabla
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your `test.cls` then will be

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage[french]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}}
\endinput
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm confused as to why you cannot do the \renewcommand after loading babel in the preamble, and instead you have to do it in the document itself.

Comment: @wilk You don't have to do it *in* the document. As I showed you can do it in the class file, but you need to do instruct TeX to postpone the `\renewcommand` after `\begin{document}` (not exactly after, but that's not relevant here); otherwise, it won't have any effect since the `french` module also redefines the labels `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: The way I see it using AtBeginDocument is roughly equivalent to putting the command after \begin{document}. And I was surprised that loading babel compels you to put this change to \labelitemi after \begin{document} (even through \AtBeginDocument) when you can otherwise put it before \begin{document}. It doesn't really matter in the end since I have a working solution, thanks to you.

Comment: @wilk I see. You can post, if you want, your solution as an answer (it could be helpful for other users).

Comment: The working solution is in fact your suggestion of using \AtBeginDocument