# Adding some horizontal space to an itemize environment where \tab is used

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, indentation, itemize

I would like to add some horizontal space to this itemize environment.
[image]

(Note that I use \tab). I tried using `[itemindent=4cm]` and `\addtolength{\itemindent}{4cm}` but the result is this:

[image]

How can I solve?

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabto}
\geometry{paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=100pt,text margin right=100pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\TabPositions{6cm}
  \begin{itemize}%[itemindent=4cm]
% \addtolength{\itemindent}{4cm}
    \item[\large$\Rightarrow$] Versione:              \tab\underline{\textbf{2.40}}
\vspace{0.35cm}
    \item[\large$\Rightarrow$] Ultimo aggiornamento:  \tab                  27 Aprile 2015
\vspace{0.35cm}
    \item[\large$\Rightarrow$] Realizzato da:         \tab                  M. Marcomarco
  \end{itemize}  

  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Where exactly is that horizontal spce to appear? Before the arrows? between arrows and tabbed text?

Comment: I would like to move all the block toward right. In other words: I would like to increase the space between the left margin of the page and `/Leftarrow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we define a `\newcommand` for the `\rightarrow`, called `\arrowx` (so we don't inadvertently break something), and then we can enclose the first part of your list in a `\makebox` like:

```
\makebox[<horizontal length>][<alignment>]{<text>}
```

We can even turn this into a command without having to type everything every time, like

```
\newcommand*\tabit[1]{\makebox[6cm][l]{#1}}
```

Also, the spacing between list items is controlled by `itemsep=.35cm`, no need to set it manually each time. If you want to increase the left margin, add `leftmargin=5cm` or any other number.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabto}
\geometry{paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=100pt,text margin right=100pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*\arrowx{\item[\large$\Rightarrow$]}
\newcommand*\tabit[1]{\makebox[6cm][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\TabPositions{6cm}
  \begin{itemize}[itemsep=.35cm, leftmargin=5cm]
    \arrowx \tabit{Versione:} \underline{\textbf{2.40}}
    \arrowx \tabit{Ultimo aggiornamento:}  27 Aprile 2015
    \arrowx \tabit{Realizzato da:} M. Marcomarco
\end{itemize}  

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong tool, in my opinion: a `tabular` is much simpler.

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,t]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\geometry{paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=100pt,text margin right=100pt}

\newcommand*\arrowx{\item[\large$\Rightarrow$]}
\newcommand*\tabit[1]{\makebox[6cm][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Dati}

\hspace{4cm}%
\begin{tabular}{@{$\Rightarrow$ }l@{\qquad}l@{}}
Versione:             & \underline{\textbf{2.40}} \\[2ex]
Ultimo aggiornamento: & 27 Aprile 2015 \\[2ex]
Realizzato da:        & M. Marcomarco
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After seeing Alenanno's answer, I tried putting in my original code (scroll the page up) `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=4cm]` and it worked. How about that?

Comment: @Marco `enumitem` is not really compatible with `beamer`; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer