# Given enumitem + beamer incompatibility, How do I adjust the indent of the enumerate environment?

Tags: beamer, enumerate, enumitem, incompatibility

Given the `enumitem` + `beamer` incompatibility discussed in detail [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer), How do I adjust the indent and vertical separation of the items in an `enumerate` environment?

As alluded to in a relevant post, an application might be to fit the enumeration more snugly into a `tabular` environment (via `minipage`).

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the indention by modifying `\leftmargini`. For nested levels the same can be done for `\leftmarginii` etc.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        normal spacing
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item test
            \item test
        \end{enumerate}

        adjusted

        \setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item test
            \item test
        \end{enumerate}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If this does not answer your question, please give a MWE that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks!  This is very helpful.  What has me really stumped is how to modify the indent.  I would like to make `normal spacing' and the numbers associated with each of the items horizontally aligned (zero indent) in your example above.

Comment: @JohnChris My bad. See the edit.

Comment: So this works well locally within a frame, but how could this be done globally?  Also, does the value 0.5cm have an associated variable name?  Ideally, I would like to set some variable to zero to make the enumerate environment and any preceding text horizontally aligned.