# Combining enumitem features and beamer list features

Tags: beamer, enumitem

I'm working on a `beamer` presentation and I really want to use this `enumitem` feature :

```
\begin{enumerate}[label= \fbox{P\arabic*}]
\item something
\item an other thing
\end{enumerate}
```

But `enumitem` and `beamer` cannot be used together as stated in this post : [Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer), and in my case, bullets in `itemize` list types disappear when using `enumitem`, which is sad since I really like the style of bullets in `beamer`. So my question is :
**Is there a way to produce the same result without using `enumitem` or is there a way to combine `beamer` and `enumitem` to have boxed item token and bullet at the same time ?**

Thanks you in advance for any hints on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item} {\color{black}\fbox{\footnotesize P\insertenumlabel}}
```

results in an output similar to the one you get using your `enumitem`-based code:

| `enumitem` & `article` | `beamer` & `\setbeamertemplate` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item} {\color{black}\fbox{\footnotesize P\insertenumlabel}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item something
\item an other thing
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, it works perfectly fine, here is the version I use : `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\color{black}\fbox{{\normalfont\gothfamily P\insertenumlabel}}}`