# how to adjust this list?

Tags: acronyms

I'm trying to adjust this abreviation list by adding a space in front of every word in bold.

[image]

this is the code :

```
\textbf{2TUP }  Two Tracks Unified Process ~\par
 \textbf{GSM}  Global System for Mobile Communications  ~\par
 \textbf{BTS}  Base Transceiver Station ~\par
 \textbf{BSC}  Base Station Controller ~\par
 \textbf{MSC} Mobile service Switching Center ~\par
 \textbf{BI} Business Intelligence ~\par
 \textbf{ETL} Extract Transform Load ~\par
 \textbf{KPI} Key Performance Indicator ~\par
```

could some one help me fix it please .

Comment: This is a list of acronyms and should not be setup by hand this way. Please have a look on `glossaries`, `acronyms` or `acro` package, for example

Comment: If you insist on a manual list then use a `description` list for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [clemens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/clemens) said,

> If you insist on a manual list then use a `description`

This should work:

```
\begin{description}
\item[2TUP]  Two Tracks Unified Process
 \item[GSM]  Global System for Mobile Communications
 \item[BTS]  Base Transceiver Station
 \item[BSC]  Base Station Controller
 \item[MSC] Mobile service Switching Center
 \item[BI] Business Intelligence
 \item[ETL] Extract Transform Load
 \item[KPI] Key Performance Indicator
\end{description}
```

If you need more indentation before the bold words, I would advise you to take a look at this post: [Indenting description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9760/indenting-description-lists)