# Hanging indent for text

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

Starting code is as follows. I'd like a hanging indent for first text column:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\section*{Random Text}
\begin{paracol}{2}
%\hangindent 
Person 1: "\blindtext"
%\hangafter
\switchcolumn \noindent
Person 2: "\blindtext"
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Random text on subsequent lines needs to be justified to the opening quote of first line. This should continue until I indicate it to end even with new lines.

Comment: Welcome! Please correct your code. It for sure won't compile like that!

Comment: Your code is still not compatible as @cfr noted.

Comment: I removed the offending duplicate article document class declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you may use the labeling-environment of the KOMA-Script bundle.

```
 \documentclass[parskip=true]{scrartcl}

 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{paracol}

 \addtokomafont{labelinglabel}{\bfseries}

 \begin{document}

 \section*{Random Text}
 \begin{paracol}{2}
 \begin{labeling}{Person 1}
 \item[Person 1] \blindtext
 \end{labeling}
 \switchcolumn
 \begin{labeling}{Person 2}
 \item[Person 2] \blindtext
 \end{labeling}
 \end{paracol}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. Never heard of the labeling environment before.

Comment: @ Jürgen Only issue is that the headers e.g. document titles, section headers are now enlarged. How to reduce font size to that of MWE?

Comment: @Quesop See my solution below. It does not use the KOMA class which has a different standard layout.

Comment: @ Quesop You may add the class option `headings=normal` or even `headings=small` [default: `headings=big`].

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you? I just use the `description` list.

### Version 1

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\section*{Random Text}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{description}
\item[Person 1] \blindtext
\end{description}
\switchcolumn
\begin{description}
\item[Person 2] \blindtext
\end{description}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 2

Here I added the `enumitem` and the `calc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip}


%% Important here
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9760
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7008
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217722
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817 <-- very relevant
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{
    leftmargin=18mm,
    itemindent=0mm,
    labelwidth=\leftmargin-\labelsep
    }

\begin{document}

\section*{Random Text}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{description}
\item[Person 1] \blindtext
\end{description}
\switchcolumn
\begin{description}
\item[Person 2] \blindtext
\end{description}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 3 -- Best solution in my Opinion

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{calc}

%% Important here
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9760
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7008
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217722
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817 <-- very relevant
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{
    leftmargin=\widthof{\normalsize\textbf{Person 99}},
    style=nextline
    }

\begin{document}

\section*{Random Text}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{description}
\item[Person 1] \blindtext
\end{description}
\switchcolumn
\begin{description}
\item[Person 2] \blindtext
\end{description}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like the "consectetuer" to align with "Lorem" and so forth for subsequent lines after the first line.

Comment: @Quesop I updated the answer